# How to use Python to grep for IP address in Shorewall rules file

Tags: python

If I use python to make a file with the list of IPs to remove and then give that file to grep as a list of regex rules I can get the result I want, but not with python on its own.

The script downloads the JSON feed from Microsoft of rule changes for Office365.

It then acts only on the "remove" changes.

I've tried using re and a simple string compare, neither have yielded any results or errors.

```py
        ips = changes['ips'] if 'ips' in changes else []
        ip4s = [ip for ip in ips if '.' in ip]

        for ip in ip4s:
            ip_rule = 'net:' + ip
            with open('/etc/shorewall/rules', 'r') as rules_file:
                with open('/tmp/rules', 'w') as tmp_rules_file:
                    for line in rules_file:
                        if not ip_rule in line:
                            tmp_rules_file.write(line)
```

The actual script has 3 sections for regex URLs, domains, and IPs.

The first two work, but not the IP section. It doesn't come up with any errors or any changes.

What's supposed to happen is that it creates a temporary file that does not contain the shorewall rules that should be deleted.

Then when I vimdiff the old rules file and the temporary one I can see what needs to be deleted.

The actual result is that both files are exactly the same.

Further testing outside of python show that there are 211 lines that should be deleted.

I'm new to python, so assuming I've tripped over something and just can't see it.

Comment: Can you give some example lines and ips (Don't use real ones)? Let's narrow this down to an example that doesn't work and make it work.

Comment: Also, is the regex relevant to this?

Comment: The IPs are public. Here's a link to the JSON file from Microsoft:  

https://endpoints.office.com/changes/worldwide/2018072800?ClientRequestId=b10c5ed1-bad1-445f-b386-b919946339a7  

A shorewall rule line would follow this pattern:  

ACCEPT lan net:0.0.0.0/24  

I'm grepping for:  

net:0.0.0.0/24

Comment: OK, fine. So my list in the start at an answer still works. What do you want as output? A file "that does not contain the shorewall rules that should be deleted." Do you mean that - that says what it doesn't contain. What should it contain? Are you trying to write out IP addresses that are no longer needed in some list?

Comment: I'm not allowed to automatically delete lines in the /etc/shorewall/rules file. So my script is supposed to write out a temporary file that is how it should be if I could delete lines. Using your IP list that would mean that the line with 1.1.1.1 in it would be deleted in the temporary file. And when I then compare the 2 files, that deleted line would be the only difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using files let's try this with a small example with lists. You can do `for line in file` or `for line in list` so could make a function in the long run that you can send any iterable into. Which means you can write unit tests, show minimal example to get help.

So, let's have our ips

```
ip4s=["1.1.1.1", "2.2.2.2"]
```

and input and output "files":

```
rules_file = ['net:1.1.1.1', 'net:3.3.3.3']
tmp_rules_file = []
```

(For example -  presume you can use your regex to get the format the way you need it)

Right. So, when we do our loops:

```
for ip in ip4s:
  ip_rule = 'net:' + ip
  for line in rules_file:
    if not ip_rule in line:
        tmp_rules_file.append(line)
```

So, for each `ip4s` we look at each line in the old rules file, one at a time.
Every line that does not have `"1.1.1.1"` gets written...

In this example, `1.1.1.1` does match the first IP, so is not written to `tmp_rules_file`.
However, `3.3.3.3` doesn't match so gets written to `tmp_rules_file`.

The next IP is `2.2.2.2` - which matches neither line, so when you look back over the whole file (again) both lines of the rules file get put in the temp file, ending up with:

```
>>> tmp_rules_file
['net:3.3.3.3', 'net:1.1.1.1', 'net:3.3.3.3']
```

This shows what's going wrong.

To find things in one list that are not in the other, you can use a list comprehension:

```
[ip for ip in ip4s if 'net:'+ip not in rules_file]
```

This just gives `['2.2.2.2']` in this case.

For larger data you might want to use a set and try the set difference operations.

The main part of your issue is checking for one thing against every line of the file - if it matches one, it won't match the others, so gets written back out.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all IPv4 and IPv6 addresses with the following regex. 
  You should read the J-son file as a simple string.
  The `set` can filter the duplication of elements of your list.

```
import re

json_as_str = """
"version": "2019042900",
    "impact": "AddedUrl",
    "add": {
    ....
    ....
    ....
]
"""

ip_four = list(set(re.findall(r"(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}(?:/\d\d?)?", json_as_str)))
ip_six = list(set([x[0] for x in re.findall(r"(([0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}:){1,7}[0-9a-fA-F]{0,4})", json_as_str)]))
print("IPv4: %r" % ip_four)
print("IPv6: %r" % ip_six)
print("Number of Ipv4: %s" % len(ip_four))
print("Number of Ipv6: %s" % len(ip_six))
```

Output:

```
>>> python test.py 
IPv4: [... many many items ...]
IPv6: [... many many items ...]
Number of Ipv4: 324
Number of Ipv6: 379
```